# pausing and stopping threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, backgroundworker, monitor

I have the following code which is working but it is very dirty. Actually the code is just fine except the part I added: a pause and a stop button. I'm new to c# so any help would be apreciated.

```
    private void pause_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start = false; pause = true; stop = false;
        guiUpdate();
        PauseEvent.Reset();
    }

    private void stop_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pause == true)
        {
            PauseEvent.Set();
            pause = false;
            this.start_button.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.resume_button_Click);
        }
        start = false; stop = true;
    }

    private int activeThreads = 0;
    private Thread thread;
    private void DoWork(object sender)
    {
        string line = null;
        ereader = new StreamReader(MY_LIST);
        do
        {
            lock (ereader)
            {
                PauseEvent.WaitOne();
                line = ereader.ReadLine();
            }

            //
            //other commands for processing & building the argument
            //

            lock (signal)
            {
                ++activeThreads;
            }

            thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(
                o =>
                {
                    processit((object)o);
                    lock (signal)
                    {
                        --activeThreads;
                        Monitor.Pulse(signal);
                    }
                }));
            thread.Start(argument);

            lock (signal)
            {
                while (activeThreads > maxthreads)
                    Monitor.Wait(signal);
            }

            lock (signal)
            {
                if (!start)
                {
                    showwaiting(true);//shows an animated gif with a "please wait" msg
                    while (activeThreads > 0)
                        Monitor.Wait(signal);
                    showwaiting(false);
                    if (stop == true)
                    {
                        this._BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (ereader.Peek() != -1);
        showwaiting(true);
        lock (signal)
        {
            while (activeThreads > 0)
                Monitor.Wait(signal);
        }
        showwaiting(false);
    }


    private void _BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        start = false; stop = true;
        guiUpdate();
    }
```

**what exactly can I do to avoid those duplicate commands inside and outside the loop ?**

Comment: Don't use `if (pause == true)`, `if (pause)` will suffice, plus I'd name it "paused" as it follows the, you could add "is" on the front and it would still make sense. This code needs a bit of a tidy. You should consider using events to control the showwaiting calls.

Comment: In addition, I think I would change all those `bool` variables to a single `enum`. Perhaps with constants such as: `Start`, `Paused`, `Stop`. That way there can only be one state and you don't have to remember which other variables to change the state of.

Comment: thank you, but do you have any idea how to get rid of that duplicate activethreads loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned in the question comments are suggestions about code practice changes.

- Do not use `== true` or `== false` when checking a boolean variable in a condition. (Jeff)
- Use an enumerate to represent the state instead of multiple boolean variables.

I would also add:

- Use proper C# naming conventions. For your methods if there are multiple words, capitalize all words. (e.g. instead of `showwaiting` use `ShowWaiting`).

For your small loops, you don't really need to optimize them out though there is more than a simple loop. So you could refactor them to a separate method along with all the code that is the same:

```
private void ShowAndWait()
{
    showwaiting(true);
    lock (signal)
    {
        while (activeThreads > 0)
            Monitor.Wait(signal);
    }
    showwaiting(false);
}
```

Note that it is fine for the same thread to lock on a monitor that it previously acquired. This is a fast operation since the thread already owns the lock. You can then call this method from both places.

Comment: you're right about the bool condition, thanks. I cleaned it a little bit